# Where are the source codes of contracts developed in Parity saved?

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

I programmed a few contracts through the browser on my local Parity node. They have all disappeared. This is obviously very annoying, and I want them back. (I have a backup, but it's outdated and missing some additions and changes I made)

I am on Windows 10.

I have checked the Parity folders in AppData and Program Files, but I can't find anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that they are stored in the Local Storage of your browser.

I probably deleted them when clearing my browser cache at some point.

Personally, I find it a bad idea to store important data like source code in such volatile storage, which is prone to be accidentally deleted.